# Выполнение одной подпрограммы множеством потоков

Tags: многопоточность, perl, concurrency

столкнулся с проблемой вернее с тем как заставить множество потоков выполнять одну подпрограмму,насколько я понял в Perl для этого используется функция lock(), но при запуске кода:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use Time::HiRes qw ( time );
use threads::shared;
use Thread;
use Mutex;
my $ti=time();
my $max=1E8;
my $num_threads=4;
my $bonics :shared=0;
sub routine{
        my @Array=@_;
        $max=$Array[0] if @Array > 0;
        $max--;
        for my $num (0..$max){
        my $cont=0;
         $cont++ if ($num%5 == 0);
          $cont++ if ($num%7 == 2);
          $cont++ if ($num%9 == 0);
        {lock($bonics);$bonics++ if($cont==1)}
}
my $s=time()-$ti;
print("Entre 0 i $max hi ha $bonics numeros bonics.\n");
print("Calculus realitzats en $s segons.\n");

}
$_->join for map {threads->create(\&routine,999)} 1...$num_threads;
```

Выдает разные значения выполнения времени для одного и того же интервала чисел, возможно есть документация где нормально описано выполнения множеством потоков одной подпрограммы но я ее не нашел.
Документацию на perldoc.perl.org уже перечитывал несколько раз.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что она должна выдавать одинаковое время выполнения ? И насколько разные значения оно выдает ? Собственно сейчас у вас все потоки выполняют параллельно одну и ту же работу. Какого эффекта вы хотите достичь ?

Comment: Могу заподозрить, что вы хотели что бы каждый из потоков выполнял часть работы. Но тогда при создании потоков вы должны были передавать в них разные параметры, так, что бы каждый из них знал какую часть работы он должен выполнять. например передавать стартовое значение с которого начинать. И цикл в нем должен обрабатывать с этого стартового значения и до стартовое значение + $max / $num_threads (с учетом и правильной обработкой округлений, если они вдруг возникают. так что возможно стоило бы задавать точный диапазон значений от-до еще при вызове).

Answer (score 0):

Треды Perl будет работать в однопоточном режиме, что бы вы ни делали. То есть, всегда будет задействовано одно ядро. Если это вас не смущает, то можете использовать модули вроде `Coro`.

Но, я бы советова воспользоваться чем-то вроде `AnyEvent::Fork`/`AnyEvent::Fork::RPC`, в зависимости от задач.

Comment: `Треды Perl будет работать в однопоточном режиме, что бы вы ни делали` а можно пруф?

Comment: Наверное, мне не повезло, но когда знакомился с тредами - не встречал мультпроцессорной  реализации. Возможно, что я погорячился и счас что-то изменилось. Так что, этот аргумент можно вычеркнуть, будем считать что у тредов есть преимущество перед Coro, который всё равно быстрее, если верить Леманну. По крайней мере, так сказано в доке модуля.